# Game maker lengthdir inner implementation

Tags: game-maker

I wonder how `lenghtdir_x/y` is implemented. To my understanding this has something to do with trigonometry but since I'm a fairly new to all of this I can't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is a bit of trigonometry - namely, converting from degrees to radians, and then multiplying a sine/cosine of that angle by "length" (hence why it is called length-dir)

`lengthdir_x(l, d)` is `l * cos(d * pi / -180)`

`lengthdir_y(l, d)` is `l * sin(d * pi / -180)`

[live demo for comparison](https://yal.cc/r/gml/?mode=2d&tabs_lz=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGALgJwJYHMwBowDGA9gCYLIDEZAZhhHAAQlpQDuAOmuxAG5RoMANgwC8DAKwAGANydufASVEMCAVzRo4EFAH0UGeAwD0DAOyyuEZmx2C6cABQBGSZNwMXbj64YBqIVpYKAAWJBhoOgAeDoLuJACU7p5+ARBBoeE6AJ4xcfHxFtzWrLb2DgBMrklVDJWSKYKBIWERkTpqAM4oRDC5TIne9f6Nac2ZWe2qXT19CQVyEAtUcLT0qektUZPTMAuaKOoQDPxYqvDa9QBUKkQdDidnWihODNcADhjGDAC0TgAcknmliWNHs6zGEQmnW6u0s+0OxzQp3OKCuDA6dHuSMe2he70+Jl+AIKYAAvgBdIA)

[image]